# Nested polyrhythms

Tags: polyrhythm

In my research on polyrhythms I have discovered the term "nested polyrhythm" with regard to some of Frank Zappa's works. I have not been able to find a clear definition of it or any examples.

Would someone please explain the term to me and show me some scores where they are heavily employed?

Comment: I posted a question asking about the simplest possible nested polyrhythm - actually nested triplets. See https://music.stackexchange.com/q/38434/9426

Comment: Thank you! Your question doesn't exactly picture a nested polyrhythm, but it does mention the other instruments' parts playing 4/4 straight, which does a good job at explaining to me what it would be like. I am not certain if the score you got from your local composer qualifies as a "nested polyrhythm". Do 2+ voices have to have nested tuplets for the polyrhythm to be considered nested? I don't know. But I don't think it matters. I will try to respond to my own question later and wait for any more input in the meantime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging by the information [Brian](https://music.stackexchange.com/users/9426/brian-thomas) has kindly linked me to, the notion of "nested" polyrhythms relies on a tuplet subdivision inside of another tuplet, for example:

[image: Tricky Rhythm]

If the second voice were to play straight quarter notes in the second bar, it would create a nested polyrhythm. It is unclear whether both voices need to have nested tuplets for a polyrhythm to be considered "nested", but I assume they don't.