# How to play the 1/32-notes rhythmically relative to the base voice in Leiki Ueda's "Chronicles of Narnia"?

Tags: piano, rhythm, counterpoint

I am trying to figure out how to play the following 1/32 notes (in green) in Leiki Ueda's rendition of "The Chronicles of Narnia – The Battle".

[image]

My intuition would be to start them on the first note in the red box, but when I watched him play it on youtube, Leiki plays the 1/32s on the fourth note in the red voice. If you could elaborate in general on the entire bar, it would be very helpful. What I also find confusing is that the voice in red adds up to 11 8th notes which is not 4/4 as specified in the time signature.

Furthermore, there are two more bars that are a tad different. Do I play these the same as the first one?

[image]

[image]

Here is the link to the youtube video

Thanks in advance

P.S. To clarify the comment from @Aaron below: the video is just there for reference. I am not asking for a transcription of the recorded version. The first bar is at timestamp 0:29, the second at 0:53, and the third at 0:38.

EDIT: ok, I guess I have found the correct sheet music now. I will keep the question posted, but it seems the issue is resolved.

Here is the right version:

[image]

Comment: Are you asking how to play the notated versions or are you asking for a transcription of the recorded version? The former is fine, but the latter is off topic on this site.

Comment: I am asking how to play the notated version. I just added the video as a reference, in case it helps.

Comment: As far as I can tell, the video version is almost entirely unrelated to the notation.

Comment: Take a look at the section titled "General approach" in [this post](https://music.stackexchange.com/a/107615/70803) and see if it gives you what you need.

Comment: One important detail: the red box does *not* contain 11 8th notes. The first half of the measure is problematic, but the second half is straightforward: The top staff divides two beats into three notes, and the bottom staff splits each of those notes in two.

Comment: Working backwards, this suggests that the remaining 5 8th notes are meant to occupy one beat, which makes it strange that they don’t have double beams.

Comment: I'm glad you found a copy that makes a bit more sense, but even it has issues. For instance, good music engraving wouldn't try to put those tie lines on top of the notes! And, in m 9 left hand upper voice, it would seem to make more sense if all notes are sextuplets and the first one just happens to be a rest. Using a 5-tuplet marking makes the initial 8th rest nonsensical. Overall, I think you'd better just interpret this piece as seems right to you, and I doubt anyone will quibble.